# Skip ERD in database implementation

Tags: database-design, erd, rdbms

AS we know that entity relation diagram(ERD) is an important concept in database implementation, But I was wondering that can we skip this step when creating a small database containing a few tables i.e directly create tables in RDBMS in order to save time. or I should do all steps for better understanding i.e draw the ERD and then implement in RDBMS ?? Although it is a small database.

Just asking this question for general knowledge as I am new to this field.

Comment: How much time does it take to draw an ERD for a small database? Is this a really significant loss of time? You might catch something (small) that you missed and save you time to fix it later. You can often generate an ERD once you created the tables. Up to you.

Comment: Oh yeah, That's a good point. Suits my question well

Answer (score 3):

The ERD is simply a product of the database design phase. You can skip drawing the ERD if you can complete design in your head, but you cannot (should not) skip *designing* your database.